# When a Book of Shadows is replaced due to loss, are rituals that were inscribed in it lost?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, rituals, eldritch-invocations

While reading through Player's Handbook 5-th edition Warlock class, I found this paragraph:

> If you lose your Book of Shadows, you can perform
>   a 1-hour ceremony to receive a replacement from your
>   patron. This ceremony can be performed during a short
>   or long rest, and it destroys the previous book.

Then, later, reading through Invocations available to the Warlock, there is **Book of Ancient Secrets** Invocation, which allows the user of the Book of Shadows to inscribe rituals inside it. Comparing those 2 things, my questions is this: 
**In the event of the Warlock losing his Book of Shadows, so that a ceremony for replacement is held, does the new book contain all the rituals Warlock inscribed in it so far, or are they irrevocably lost and must be written again from scratch?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the spells *appear* and are not written by you, they would be gifts from your Patron and would reappear when you renewed your grimore.

The key wording for this interpretation is the word "appear" in the description from Book of Ancient Secrets. I would definitely rule that any spells you *wrote* in the book would be gone if the book was recreated (thus the spells you acquire in your travels are lost). However, spells that are gained through class features and can be interpreted as granted by your Patron should be restored when she restores the book via the ceremony.

Comment: This just made me smile. I didn't think there was an RAW answer to the question and then this elegant bit of reading popped up.

Comment: @GoblinTheodicy yeah I had to poke around a bit. It seems silly to leave someone out to dry on a class feature like this. (though the wizard does this)

Comment: +1 excelent answer. And it follows RAW. Accepted, thank you for your time, I`m sure my players will be much "grateful" for this clarification *evil grin*

Answer (score 26):

It returns with all inscribed rituals:

> > **Luke Anderson‏** @SaunaNotSawna · [23 Apr 2016](https://twitter.com/SaunaNotSawna/status/723972214123454464)
> >     @JeremyECrawford When I replace my Pact of the Tome Tome, does it come back with all of my rituals/cantrips still in it?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford‏** @JeremyECrawford · [26 Apr 2016](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/725190655199330304)
>   @SaunaNotSawna Yes.

---

> > **Qzotia‏** @SorcererQzot · [24 Apr 2016](https://twitter.com/SorcererQzot/status/724325197889699840)
> >     @JeremyECrawford @mikemearls @dungeonbastard A tome warlock receives a replacement Book of Shadows. Were inscribed rituals lost?
>
> **Mike Mearls‏** @mikemearls · [25 Apr 2016](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/724642279231627264)
>   @SorcererQzot @JeremyECrawford @dungeonbastard no

I think the reason that the ink is so expensive would be because in infuses magic on a level beyond its literal appearance on paper. Another argument for this is that the old book crumbles away both when replaced and when you die, implying that it is less a physical book in the sense of a wizard's spellbook and more a maintained boon from your patron — the reason it crumbles when replaced is that it is the same book and there can be only one.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer because it has sources to the answer from Mearls and Crawford that contradict the accepted answer.  The tweets may be from 2 years after the answer, but they give the correct answer.

Comment: Note that [Jeremy Crawford's (and Mike Mearls') tweets are not considered official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi). You may want to update your answer accordingly.